# Recovery hard drive

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, backup

I accidentally formatted my RECOVERY hard drive (of file system type RAW). Actually, I don't really know what was inside it and what was it for, I thought that inside it were all my documents, from the latest backup, in fact I formatted it because I wanted to do the backup in another external hard drive. At this moment, to use this empty hard drive (RAW), Windows tells me that I have to format this unity.

- Can you tell me what a file system of type RAW is?
- What kind of files / programs were inside it? (drivers)?
- How grave were my actions (formatting the RECOVERY drive)?
- How can I solve all this?
- Please, tell me some good guides to learn about this things not to
  committ the same errors.

I have an HP, model: Pavillon dv6. I have Windows 7 and in a partition Ubuntu. I have also another empty partition for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had an HP PC, if I recall, this area contains information for restoring a broken C: drive OS to the factory standard or running diags.   This is something that both DELL and HP provide but is not standard.

When you started using the system, I believe it asks if you want to make a recovery CD (you can make a maximum of 2, if I recall).  This recovery CD can be also used to restore a broken Window OS to HP factory specs.  This is because HP did not distribute a Windows OS CD with their systems.  Did you make a recovery CD? (hope so)

I'd say that if you are not worried about system recovery to HP initial, you are ok formatting the area and using it.  It's not that big however.

BTW, I used that recovery CD twice to recover my HP system at that time.  One thing I did notice was that it did not delete anything just overwrite whatever it needed to.  I still had to reinstall the applications of course because eventhough the programs were present, the various registry stuff was not restored.